# Cypress click button and keep the mouse on the button

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I am testing a dropdown button, when I click the button, the dropdown menu shows up. However, if the mouse leaves the button and menu, the dropdown menu will hide. If I use `click`, it will fail with reason the button detached on the DOM. If I use `click({force:true})`, it will throw the ResizeObserver loop limit exceeded exception. Then I use `realClick` the button, no fail or errors, but still, the dropdown menu can not be seen. I think it's because the mouse is in other position so it hides (or maybe some other weird reasons). I tried `realHover` before or after the `realClick`, still no dropdown menu. How can I keep the mouse on the button after `realClick`?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways of doing this.

cy.get('.menu-item').trigger('mouseover').realClick()

Check https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover#Trigger for more info.

Comment: I tried, mouseover was succeeded(button became blue), but click did not happen. If click succeeded there will be a purple border. I did not see the border, that's the issue.

Comment: I have edited the answer, hope this works

Comment: I added a `wait` in the beginning and now the dropdown menu can show

Answer (score 0):

How about you use `mousedown` and then `mouseup`.

```js
cy.get('selector').trigger('mousedown')
cy.get('selector').trigger('mouseup')
```